# How can i fix an anaconda environment not activating?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have been trying to learn how to use anaconda and I'm having a hard time because of this. If I create an environment and try to activate it doesn't seem to work because the python version it outputs is not the same I typed in, instead it outputs the version of python in the conda base environment.

```
PS C:\Users\gustb> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\gustb\anaconda3

PS C:\Users\gustb> conda create -n test python==3.9
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\gustb\anaconda3\envs\test

  added / updated specs:
    - python==3.9


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2023.05.30-haa95532_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1u-h2bbff1b_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-23.1.2-py39haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.9.0-h6244533_2
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-67.8.0-py39haa95532_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.41.2-h2bbff1b_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2023c-h04d1e81_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py39haa95532_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate test
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\gustb> conda activate test
PS C:\Users\gustb> python --version
Python 3.10.12
PS C:\Users\gustb> python
Python 3.10.12 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jul  5 2023, 19:09:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
PS C:\Users\gustb>
```

So i run `conda info` to check it shows that there is no active environment.

```
PS C:\Users\gustb> conda activate test
PS C:\Users\gustb> conda info

     active environment : None
     ...
```

This is my first time uploading a question and am not an English native so sorry I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear.